# Is there a Greek myth of Poseidon "dating" his daughter in the form of a dolphin?

Tags: ancient-greece, greek-mythology

On Saturday Night Live, there was a skit in which Greek god Poseidon said that he took the form of a dolphin and raped his daughter. Do we have literary or other evidence for such a myth?

It might have been a joke, I know there's plenty of myths about Zeus having sex in the form of an animal and I think a similar myth about Poseidon could exist.

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic here.

Comment: You are right, there is indeed a myth about Zeus transforming into an animal to mate with a female human. I am rather more doubtful of the scenario you present here though.

Comment: @Noldorin: I think that you are talking about the Europa myth ;)

Comment: @WladimirPalant: That's the one, cheers. My Greek mythology isn't very good. ;-)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: I invite you to join me in voting to close this question. You just got enough reputation (via upvotes) to do so.

Comment: @Noldorin: Well, it's quite a famous one, it's even on the [Greek Euro coins](http://www.eurocoins.co.uk/images/2002greece2euroobv240.jpg).

Comment: @Wladimir: Yes okay, rub in my ignorance, thanks. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poseidon is associated with dolphins. There are also stories of him having various sexual encounters with a large number of other humans and gods. These do include rapes and also transformations into other animals. However, I don't find an exact match for your line. I did however find that Melantho, Daughter of Deucalion, was raped by Neptune as a dolphin.

In Greek mythology, sex plays a big part. Many of the stories concern unpleasant aspects of sexuallity.

Comment: I think that the Melantho myth is originally Greek and talks about Poseidon. However, the common reference for that myth is Ovid's Metamorphoses where he talks about Neptun of course.

Comment: I think you are right.  The exact story wasn't part of the mythology.  (Although, it is difficult to be sure on a negative.)  It was just a parody of mythology that through together a lot of common themes.

Comment: Unpleasant for the victim ;D